# How can i fix the button to switch between disabled and enabled states using react and javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

if the email is valid then add button is enabled. if email is invalide then add button is disabled.

below is my code,

```
function Parent() {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [isDisabled, setIsDisabled] = React.useState(true);
    const regex = /^(?:"[ .a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_{|}~-]+)*"|[.a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_{|}~-]+)*)@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)*[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?$/;

    const isValid = (value)=> {
        return regex.test(String(value).toLowerCase());
    }

    const onEmailChange = (event: any) => {
        setEmail(event.target.value);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        setIsDisabled(!isEmail(email));
    }, [email]);

    return (
        <input
            type="text"
            onChange={onEmailChange}/>
        <button disabled={isDisabled}>add</button>
    );
}
```

the regex above works perfect. but the problem is when i type the email say "user@" then the add button is disabled when user types in next character say now the email is "user@i" then add button is enabled. now when user types in "user@i." then the add button is disabled and enabled when this "user@i.i" entered and so on.

how can i fix this behavior??? could someone help me with this. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is with regex, it doesn't check for ending of the email, you need to update your regex with below

```
const regex_email = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
```

Demo : https://regexr.com/59qcb

Comment: thanks it gives me unnecessary escape character here s@\", (\".+\")

Comment: can you share full email?

Comment: i mean i get error unnecessary escape character at places  s@\", (\".+\")